# Search DNS by IP for duplicates

Tags: powershell, dns

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to search my DNS server for hostnames that have the same IP, so I can have the script remove the not-used entry.
Here is the line I am using to pull the list of hostnames and IPs

```
Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName "dnsserver" -ZoneName "zone" -RRType A | Select HostName,@{Name='RecordData';Expression={$_.RecordData.IPv4Address}}
```

This returns the entire list of hostnames and IPs I need.  Now, I just need a way to search this list by IP in a way that will show me any hostname with that IP...

Comment: Seems like you're looking to filter, instead of "selecting", `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName "dnsserver" -ZoneName "zone" -RRType A | Where-Object { $_.RecordData.IPv4Address -eq 'the ip im looking for here' }`

Comment: Pipe to a `Where-Object -Property "RecordData" -EQ "IP.ADD.RES.HERE"`